# Selenium Unable to Close Modal Window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There's a modal window on this page: https://shop.wegmans.com. It doesn't popup every time but it's frequent enough that I can reproduce this issue.

On the page I'm running the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_experimental_option(
    "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
prefs = {"credentials_enable_service": False,
     "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
     "useAutomationExtension": False}
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.maximize_window()
# Logging in
# ....
# ....
wait.until(EC.title_contains('Home'))
try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("modal")
    print("Modal Found")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Modal not found")
```

Every time the page loads with the modal the div is there and every time the console prints `Modal not found`.

The site is using Angular and React. I don't know if this is because of the way the DOM is generated.

How can I make Selenium see the modal so that I can close it?

Comment: please include the modal HTML in your question for more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the modal window on the page https://shop.wegmans.com doesn't popup every time, you can surround the `click()` on the modal within a `try-except{}` block with a specific timeout as follows:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "modal"))).click()
    print("Modal found and clicked")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Modal wasn't found")
```